# How to solve the java.lang.NullPointerException on a GUI (Generated Code)

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I'm trying to make a simple Network Project with Java Sockets,where a Client is booking a parking space (through a Graphical User Interface) from a Server who possesses an ArrayList of all available parking spaces.
The class ParkingSpace consists of 3 attributes:
-The ID of the parking space
-The coordinates
-And the availability

Firstly the client will press the jButton1 to start the connection to the server and receive the list object with the available parking spaces.
The Client GUI has a jTable in which the ID and corresponding coordinates of the available spaces will preview,and a ComboBox on which the client will select the ID of the space of his desire.Once the space is selected,the client then will press the jButton2 to send the new updated list object to the server,with the selected space availability changed to false.

Just to mention that is missing from the server the functionality to receive the book to the Server and what to do with the booked space,but I will implement that on a later stage.

```
//CLASS ParkingSpace

package exams2013sockets;

import java.io.*;

/**
 *
 * @author Alexandros
 */
public class ParkingSpace implements Serializable {
    private String id;
    private String coordinates;
    private boolean availability;

    public ParkingSpace(String id, String coordinates, boolean availability) {
        this.id = id;
        this.coordinates = coordinates;
        this.availability = availability;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getCoordinates() {
        return coordinates;
    }

    public void setCoordinates(String coordinates) {
        this.coordinates = coordinates;
    }

    public boolean isAvailability() {
        return availability;
    }

    public void setAvailability(boolean availability) {
        this.availability = availability;
    }
    
}

===========================================

//CLASS Server

package exams2013sockets;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
/**
 *
 * @author Alexandros
 */
public class Server implements Serializable {
    
    ServerSocket listenSocket;
    Socket server;
    ObjectInputStream ois;
    ObjectOutputStream oos;
    
    public void startServer() {
        try {
            listenSocket=new ServerSocket(7000);
            while (true) {
                server=listenSocket.accept();
                OutputStream os=server.getOutputStream();
                oos=new ObjectOutputStream(os);
                InputStream is=server.getInputStream();
                ois=new ObjectInputStream(is);
                sendListToClient();
                closeServer();
            }
        } catch (SocketException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        
    }
    
    public void closeServer() {
        try {
            ois.close();
            oos.close();
            server.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
            
    public ArrayList listOfSpaces() {
        ArrayList<ParkingSpace> list = new ArrayList<>();
        ParkingSpace p1 = new ParkingSpace("A01","1,1",true);
        ParkingSpace p2 = new ParkingSpace("A02","1,2",true);
        ParkingSpace p3 = new ParkingSpace("A03","1,3",true);
        ParkingSpace p4 = new ParkingSpace("A04","1,4",true);
        ParkingSpace p5 = new ParkingSpace("A05","1,5",true);
        ParkingSpace p6 = new ParkingSpace("A06","1,6",true);
        ParkingSpace p7 = new ParkingSpace("A07","1,7",true);
        ParkingSpace p8 = new ParkingSpace("A08","1,8",true);
        ParkingSpace p9 = new ParkingSpace("A09","1,9",true);
        ParkingSpace p10 = new ParkingSpace("A10","1,10",true);
        ParkingSpace p11 = new ParkingSpace("B01","2,1",true);
        ParkingSpace p12 = new ParkingSpace("B02","2,2",true);
        ParkingSpace p13 = new ParkingSpace("B03","2,3",true);
        ParkingSpace p14 = new ParkingSpace("B04","2,4",true);
        ParkingSpace p15 = new ParkingSpace("B05","2,5",true);
        ParkingSpace p16 = new ParkingSpace("B06","2,6",true);
        ParkingSpace p17 = new ParkingSpace("B07","2,7",true);
        ParkingSpace p18 = new ParkingSpace("B08","2,8",true);
        ParkingSpace p19 = new ParkingSpace("B09","2,9",true);
        ParkingSpace p20 = new ParkingSpace("B10","2,10",true);
        list.add(p1);list.add(p2);list.add(p3);
        list.add(p4);list.add(p5);list.add(p6);
        list.add(p7);list.add(p8);list.add(p9);
        list.add(p10);list.add(p11);list.add(p12);
        list.add(p13);list.add(p14);list.add(p15);
        list.add(p16);list.add(p17);list.add(p18);
        list.add(p19);list.add(p20);
        return list;
    }
    
    public void sendListToClient() {
        try {
            oos.writeObject(listOfSpaces());
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Server.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Server serv=new Server();
        serv.startServer();
    }    
}

==========================================

//CLASS Client

package exams2013sockets;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;


/**
 *
 * @author Alexandros
 */
public class Client extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    Socket client;
    ObjectInputStream ois;
    ObjectOutputStream oos;
    private ArrayList<ParkingSpace> serverList;
    private ArrayList<ParkingSpace> updatedList;
    
    /**
     * Creates new form Client
     */
    public Client() {
        initComponents();
    }
    
    public void startClient() {
        try {
            client=new Socket("127.0.0.1", 7000);
            OutputStream os=client.getOutputStream();
            oos=new ObjectOutputStream(os);
            InputStream is=client.getInputStream();
            ois=new ObjectInputStream(is);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
    public void closeClient() {
        try {
            ois.close();
            oos.close();
            client.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
    
    public void addRowsToTable(ArrayList<ParkingSpace> paramList){
        DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) jTable2.getModel();
        serverList.addAll(paramList);
        Object rowData[] = new Object[20];
        for (int i=0; i<serverList.size(); i++) {
            if (serverList.get(i).isAvailability()==true) {
            rowData[0] = serverList.get(i).getId();
            rowData[1] = serverList.get(i).getCoordinates();
            model.addRow(rowData); }
        }
        
    }
    
    public void addOptionsToComboBox(){
        for (int i=0; i<jTable2.getRowCount(); i++) {
        jComboBox1.addItem(jTable2.getValueAt(i,0).toString());
        }
    }
    
    public void bookSpace(ArrayList<ParkingSpace> paramList){
        updatedList.addAll(paramList);
        Object selectedItem = jComboBox1.getSelectedItem();
        for (int i=0; i<updatedList.size(); i++) {
            if (updatedList.get(i).getId().equals(selectedItem.toString())) {
                updatedList.get(i).setAvailability(false);
            }
        }
    }

    public void UpdateListToServer() {
        try {
            oos.writeObject(updatedList);
            closeClient();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Server.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
    
    
    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jScrollPane2 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jTable2 = new javax.swing.JTable();
        jComboBox1 = new javax.swing.JComboBox<>();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jTable2.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
            new Object [][] {

            },
            new String [] {
                "ID", "Coordinates"
            }
        ) {
            boolean[] canEdit = new boolean [] {
                false, false
            };

            public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
                return canEdit [columnIndex];
            }
        });
        jScrollPane2.setViewportView(jTable2);

        jComboBox1.setMaximumRowCount(21);
        jComboBox1.setToolTipText("");

        jButton1.setText("Available Positions");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton2.setText("Select Position");
        jButton2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton2ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jScrollPane2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 213, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 126, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                    .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(jComboBox1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 57, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jButton2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addGap(99, 99, 99))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(39, 39, 39)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jScrollPane2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 364, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addContainerGap(23, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jComboBox1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 35, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                        .addComponent(jButton2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 36, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGap(90, 90, 90))))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        /*Receive the list object from the server and fill the jTable with the available spaces */
        ArrayList<ParkingSpace> recvFromServ = null;
            try {
                recvFromServ =(ArrayList<ParkingSpace>)ois.readObject();
            } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(Client.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            addRowsToTable(recvFromServ);
            addOptionsToComboBox();
    
    }                                        

    private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // Button to select the Space and make it unavailable
        bookSpace(serverList);
        UpdateListToServer();
   
    }                                        
        
        
        
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Client.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Client.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Client.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Client.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
            new Client().setVisible(true);
        });
        
        Client cl=new Client();
        cl.startClient();
        
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
    private javax.swing.JComboBox<String> jComboBox1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane2;
    private javax.swing.JTable jTable2;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

The errors I get when starting the client are these:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusStyle.validate(NimbusStyle.java:298)
    at javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusStyle.getValues(NimbusStyle.java:806)
    at javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusStyle.getInsets(NimbusStyle.java:485)
    at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthStyle.installDefaults(SynthStyle.java:913)
    at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthLookAndFeel.updateStyle(SynthLookAndFeel.java:265)
    at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthRootPaneUI.updateStyle(SynthRootPaneUI.java:93)
    at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthRootPaneUI.installDefaults(SynthRootPaneUI.java:59)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicRootPaneUI.installUI(BasicRootPaneUI.java:56)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.setUI(JComponent.java:660)
    at javax.swing.JRootPane.setUI(JRootPane.java:474)
    at javax.swing.JRootPane.updateUI(JRootPane.java:484)
    at javax.swing.JRootPane.<init>(JRootPane.java:371)
    at javax.swing.JFrame.createRootPane(JFrame.java:286)
    at javax.swing.JFrame.frameInit(JFrame.java:267)
    at javax.swing.JFrame.<init>(JFrame.java:190)
    at exams2013sockets.Client.<init>(Client.java:30)
    at exams2013sockets.Client.main(Client.java:246)
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusStyle.validate(NimbusStyle.java:298)
    at javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusStyle.installDefaults(NimbusStyle.java:227)
    at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthStyle.installDefaults(SynthStyle.java:916)
    at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthLookAndFeel.updateStyle(SynthLookAndFeel.java:265)
    at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthScrollBarUI.updateStyle(SynthScrollBarUI.java:130)
    at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthScrollBarUI.installDefaults(SynthScrollBarUI.java:67)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicScrollBarUI.installUI(BasicScrollBarUI.java:172)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.setUI(JComponent.java:660)
    at javax.swing.JScrollBar.setUI(JScrollBar.java:207)
    at javax.swing.JScrollBar.updateUI(JScrollBar.java:227)
    at javax.swing.JScrollBar.<init>(JScrollBar.java:161)
    at javax.swing.JScrollBar.<init>(JScrollBar.java:176)
    at javax.swing.JScrollPane$ScrollBar.<init>(JScrollPane.java:718)
    at javax.swing.JScrollPane.createVerticalScrollBar(JScrollPane.java:873)
    at javax.swing.JScrollPane.<init>(JScrollPane.java:299)
    at javax.swing.JScrollPane.<init>(JScrollPane.java:351)
    at exams2013sockets.Client.initComponents(Client.java:109)
    at exams2013sockets.Client.<init>(Client.java:31)
    at exams2013sockets.Client.lambda$main$0(Client.java:243)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
C:\Users\Alexandros\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\12.5\executor-snippets\run.xml:111: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\Alexandros\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\12.5\executor-snippets\run.xml:94: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 8 seconds)
```

From what I read the NullPointerException occurs when refering to an Object that hasn't been created.But the form which I created has generated the code automatically.

How to deal with this??

PS: At this stage of the project I want to receive the object list from server to the client and with the press of the jButton1 to preview the spaces on the jTable

========================

After I removed the code for the "Look and Feel",the related to this errors seems to be gone.

The errors I get now are the following (including some with connectivity problems):

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:75)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:476)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:218)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:162)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:394)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:606)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:555)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:451)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:228)
    at exams2013sockets.Client.startClient(Client.java:36)
    at exams2013sockets.Client.main(Client.java:249)
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at exams2013sockets.Client.jButton1ActionPerformed(Client.java:190)
    at exams2013sockets.Client.access$000(Client.java:19)
    at exams2013sockets.Client$2.actionPerformed(Client.java:141)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:262)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6539)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3318)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6304)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2239)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2297)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4904)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4535)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4476)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2283)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:760)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:84)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:733)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:730)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a bug in either Swing or any of the related components (like the generator).
Normally it should not happen in autogenerated projects.

I found some examples of it in different projects using Swing:

https://bz.apache.org/netbeans/show_bug.cgi?id=258559

https://github.com/FeraGroup/FTCVortexScoreCounter/issues/23

No workaround has been mentioned.
I think its worth trying to remove components / buttons from your form / app one by one to understand what is causing this issue. There is probably no simpler solution..

Answer (score 0):

It has to do something with the UI Manager of the GUI.Inside the main of Client class which exists the GUI there is code to set the "Look and Feel"...but I haven't found how to solve it yet.

Answer (score 0):

To verify this is related to the look and feel, remove `javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(...)` from your code and run the application again. Do you still see the problem?

As from the stack trace this looks like a problem related to a scrollbar, check if you have any component that uses a scrollbar or scrollpane. Investigate what happens if you change that.

Try your application with different JVMs. Oracle, OpenJDK, ... whatever you find.

Remember to write down the results, they are valuable for further troubleshooting.

Comment: You want me to remove only the line javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());  ...or all the try-catch block??

Comment: There is indeed a jTable that uses a ScrollPane in the Form

Comment: You can remove that one line, you can remove the whole block. There is not much difference. Just try and let us know the result.